# The yearling badge notification is duplicated

Tags: bug, badges, notifications

Today I received my yearling badge for Code Review, but the notification was duplicated:

[image: Screenshot of the notification window.]

Comment: For some reason or other, the powers that be decided to make child-meta site icons washed out and colourless.

Comment: The notification is not duplicated. You earned one on main and one on meta.